# Sending request data with case sensitive keys in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

As part of a form, I am sending a JSON object in a put request to a Rails backend. The request data looks something like this:

```
{"choiceNames": {
  "Key Name A": true,
  "Key Name B": true
}}
```

The example is contrived but the point is that the key names are case sensitive. In the Rails controller, when looking at the data with `params`, all of the keys have been downcased.

```
{"choiceNames" => {
  "key name a" => true,
  "key name b" => true
}}
```

How do I prevent Rails from doing this downcasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must read, [6.2.2.1. The RFC for URIs: Case Normalization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.2.1) which stated,

> When a URI uses components of the generic syntax, the component
> syntax equivalence rules always apply; namely, that the scheme and
> host are case-insensitive and therefore should be normalized to
> lowercase.

Obtain capitalised form inside controller.